# proguard does not adapt resources inside jar file

Tags: java, jar, obfuscation, proguard

I use proguard like this:

```
<proguard configuration="${proguard.config}" ignorewarnings="true">
        <libraryjar dir="${build.lib}" filter="!some**.jar"/>
        <injar file="${build.dir.result}/some.jar"/>
        <injar>
            <fileset refid="another.jars"/>
        </injar>
        <outjar file="${build.dir.result}/some_obf.jar"/>
        <keep name="${entrypoint.class}">
            <method name="main"/>
        </keep>
 </proguard>
```

in config I also have options(and many more -keep):

```
-adaptresourcefilenames    **.properties
-adaptresourcefilecontents
```

In jars I have compiled classes and spring xml configs. Configs located in META-INF/spring/.
All classes names are obfuscated normally(checked), all classes from xml's are obfuscated and have new name. I want to replace fully qualified classes names in spring xml's with obfuscated ones. Thats why I add adaptresourcefilecontents parameter, but xml's are untouched.
What's wrong?

Comment: I suspect that proguard can't detect that, I faced same problem and have to keep the classes unchanged for classes that have relation with a resource file.

Comment: You need to tell proguard to process your xml files - something like

`-adaptresourcefilecontents **/*.xml`